# Sorting sometimes does not work in a Grid Panel, but most of the time does

Tags: extjs

EXT version 3.3.0

I have a grid panel with sortable columns.  It works with 90% of the users.  But with some users, the first column (which is an integer) renders as not sortable.  Even when you click on the pop up menu above the column, the "Sort Ascending" and "Sort Descending" are greyed out. I cannot replicate this error, but I have seen it on other user workstations.  Here are more details:

1. The ColoumnModel uses a RowNumberer
2. All columns are sortable.
3. The grid panel uses a viewConfig w/ "forceFit" set to false, and "autoFill" set to true.

I don't have the source code on this network, o/w I would just paste it in.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you will get an answer without some sort of working example. You can get code by just copying the source from Firebug - unless it's been compressed.

Comment: Even without the source, I'm concerned about what "some users" means. Are they always the same users? Does the problem occur on specific browsers/operating systems? If we knew what the common traits were, it would help narrow down the possible solutions.

Comment: The problem occurs in Firefox 3.6  I do not have access to the network where this runs, O/W I would paste in the code

Comment: The problem occurs with Windows XP, Firefox 3.6, and the same users.  We cannot replicate

Answer (score 1):

I remember I had similar issue some time ago, and the deal was that ExtJs grid restores it's state from cookies incorrectly. After some debugging I added the following patch:

```
Ext.override(Ext.grid.GridPanel, {
    applyState: function (state) {
        var cm = this.colModel,
            cs = state.columns,
            store = this.store,
            s,
            c,
            colIndex;

        if (cs) {
            for (var i = 0, len = cs.length; i < len; i++) {
                s = cs[i];
                c = cm.getColumnById(s.id);
                if (c) {
                    colIndex = cm.getIndexById(s.id);
                    cm.setState(colIndex, {
                        hidden: s.hidden,
                        width: s.width,
                        sortable: s.sortable,
                        fixed: cm.columns[colIndex].fixed
                    });
                    if (colIndex != i) {
                        cm.moveColumn(colIndex, i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (store) {
            s = (state.sort instanceof Array) ? state.sort[0] : state.sort;
            if (s) {
                store[store.remoteSort && store.groupBy ? 'setDefaultSort' : 'sort'](s.field, s.direction);
            }
            s = state.group;
            if (store.groupBy) {
                if (s) {
                    store.groupBy(s);
                }
                else {
                    store.clearGrouping();
                }
            }

        }
        var o = Ext.apply({}, state);
        delete o.columns;
        delete o.sort;
        Ext.grid.GridPanel.superclass.applyState.call(this, o);
    }
});
```

The only extra thing it does it restore fixed property from the cookies as well.